# Why is Google Lighthouse recommending image formats it doesn't support?

Tags: image, pageload, page-load-time, lighthouse

I ran a Lighthouse audit on my site and received what you see below.

[image: google lighthouse results for image format]

However, when I go into [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com)...

For **JPEG 2000**:
[image: caniuse results for JPEG 2000 image format]

and For **JPEG XR**:
[image: caniuse results for JPEG XR image format]

Why would Lighthouse recommend using a format that, **1.**-isn't supported by Chrome, and **2.**-is barely supported by any browsers at all?

Answer (score 1):

Google wants to push webp, but does not want to look biased. You can just use jpg. More on this in my article [How to get a 100% Google Lighthouse score](https://www.usecue.com/blog/how-to-get-a-100-google-lighthouse-score/).

TLDR: Use SVG for vector and 50% jpg for the rest. Soon you will be able to [use webp](https://www.usecue.com/blog/has-webp-landed-yet-2/).

Comment: that link goes to a 404.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Comment: I braved the extremely blue site in this link to provide you with the "More on this" portion of this answer: `Use SVG whenever possible and heavily compressed JPG for the rest.`